# Setting diagonal of a matrix to zero

Tags: python, matrix, diagonal

```
m = [[[math.inf] * 10] for i in range(10)]

for i in range(len(m)):
    for j in range(len(m)):
        if(i == j):
            m[i][i] = 0
```

[image]

I try to insert zero And I used the debugger to watch the process go. Instead of changing it to

```
[[[0,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf],[......],[.......]]]
```

It changes it to

```
[[0], [[inf,inf,inf,inf....],[inf,inf,....]]
```

Which then causes an index out of bound error because it just reduced a 10x10 matrix to the top row being zero,
as opposed to `inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf`.

Where my goal is to set a 10x10 matrix's diagonal to all zeros.

I tried to use:

```
m = [[[math.inf] * 10] for i in range(10)]
```

Comment: 1) What language is this (Python?), 2) assuming it's Python, _carefully_ count the number of square brackets. You have three levels of nested lists while it looks like you only want two.

Comment: In particular, note that `[math.inf] * 10` is a list of length 10, while `[[math.inf] * 10]` is a list of length 1 containing a single list of length 10.

Comment: I can see I nested it to many times, I just am unsure of how to fix it. I want a 10x10 matrix generated.

Answer (score 0):

As @Christopher-Renauro pointed out, you currently have a list of length 10.

Setting the diagonal of a matrix to zeros can be easily done using Numpy.

- convert your list to a numpy array of 10x10 shape :
  new_m = np.array(m).reshape(10,10)
- use fill_diagonal() :
  fill_diagonal(new_m, val=0)